# react-ntaive-admob showing test ad banner why not original ad on emulator ?

Tags: react-native, admob

I have used React-native-admob to show google ads in my react-native application. My code for ad is given below.

```
<View style={{width:slideWidth,height:60}}>
<AdMobBanner
 bannerSize="fullBanner"
 adUnitID="some-unit-id"
 testDeviceID="EMULATOR"

 didFailToReceiveAdWithError={this.bannerError}/>
</View>
```

it is showing me this test banner

[image: screen shot]

why it is so ? why it is not showing me original ad ?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you've written

```
testDeviceID="EMULATOR"
```

Remove this line and your ads will show.

Note: In development its not recommended to test with real ads as you may accidently click on them. Better to check if it works and then revert back to test mode.

Comment: if i remove this then this test banner dont  show up

Comment: @Asad you need to add your own unique adUnitID. Instructions are in the github page

Comment: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128738?hl=en-GB&amp;visit_id=1-636322770148049560-1539848796&amp;rd=1, getting your adUnitID is pretty straight forward, this link explains how to setup your ad unit

Comment: I already have my unit ID the problem is with Ifone 5 i think